# Personal CV manager with content-customization output

Tags: pdf, information-management

I am looking for a software where I can easily create and manage a database of **all my personal CV data**, which will then allow me to **output customized CVs** (showing only particular contents) by selecting the fields that I want to include in the PDF output.

For example, complete **professional** CV with all my scientific communications and academic e-mail address VS a short **personal** resume with my volunteering work and my personal hobbies.

Mac or Linux, preferably offline and preferably free.

Comment: Why not making a complete CV and when needing a shortened version copying the file and deleting the parts you don't want. Done.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily put together a database of entries with tags such as PRO, VOLUNTARY, HOBBY, etc., with dates, entries, etc., using [LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org/) [Base](http://www.libreoffice.org/discover/base/) - this would allow you to select on one, or more, tags, sort by date  (or other criteria), and merge it into a professional looking document with output as pdf as a possibility.

- OS-X, Linux & Windows
- Free, Gratis & Open Source
- Widely Used
- Data not stored on-line, *(unless you specify otherwise).*

Comment: Thank you Steve for your input. I am really looking to find if there is any dedicated software out there capable of doing exactly this (i could not find any in my searches). If none exists, then I will develop one -> I just don't want to loose time to reinvent the wheel :)